# What is the difference between Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHub and Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient?

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-web-api, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am learning about notification hubs and on this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530747.aspx) there are two ways of registering

one from device which uses [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHub](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.messaging.notificationhub.aspx) to register from device.

second one which uses [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs.NotificationHubClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationhubclient.aspx) to register from app backend

So does it mean when I want to access notification hub from app backend I will always have to use the second one and from device the first one?

Or we can use both of them anywhere? And if that is so what are the differences in functionalities that they provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - there are different libraries for the client and backend. NotificationHub is for Windows Store applications. NotificationHubClient is for the .NET backend. Yes, you should use each library in the corresponding cases. You will not be able to install, for example, NotificationHubClient for the client Universal App - NuGet will throw the error.

Regarding the differences in functionality, your question should be clarified - you can compare both of the classes using links you provided in the question.

Comment: Done. Did I answer your question?